# how to modify folders name

Tags: perl

I have a bunch of folder in my local hard disk. Below is the folders name :

```
3 ABC
abc movie (2002)  HDTVRip  576p  Hindi  Eng  BHATTI87
Bcd [2011].720p.BRRip.x264.[Dual Audio] [Hindi+English].by K@rtik [ExD Exclusive]
def (2007)
Gaf-DVDRip-AVI
Gadks Of Wc (2012) - DVDRip - 1CD - XviD - Subs - [xDM]
Kah - DVDScr - XviD - 1CDRip - [DDR]
kaslf.kasl .Ljasj [2007] - x264 - AAC - 1 CD DVDRip - ESubs - MDG
```

I want all the name have some similarity like between each string there should be one space i.e  "Gadks Of Wc (2012) - DVDRip - 1CD - XviD - Subs - [xDM]" should be
Gadks Of Wc (2012) DVDRip 1CD XviD Subs [xDM].

My logic was :

1. Read the each folder name
2. Store all the folder name in a list
3. Do operation like split and join on  each name

Below is my script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $dir_name = "E:/movie";

opendir READ, $dir_name
    or die"Can not found it $!";

my @name = readdir(READ);
my (@split_name, $update_movie_name, $fix_movie_name);

foreach my $name (@name) {

   @split_name        = split /[\s+\/.\-]/,$name;
   $update_movie_name = movie_fun(@split_name); 
}

sub movie_fun {

    foreach my $movie (@split_name) {

        $fix_movie_name = join("",$movie);
    }

    return ($fix_movie_name);
}
```

With this script I am only getting last part of the folder name. I don't know where am I doing mistake. Please help me out of this problem. So that i can move my next step which will be deleting junk part from the name i.e "(2012) - DVDRip - 1CD - XviD - Subs - [xDM]",(2007) etc

If any body  can give me any other way to proceed for this problem then also will be fine.

Thanks

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $dir_name = "/movie";
opendir READ, $dir_name
    or die"Can not found it $!";

my @name = readdir(READ);

FOLDER:
foreach my $name (@name) {

    # process only directories (skip if folder name . or ..)
    next FOLDER if ( (not -d $dir_name.$name) || ($name =~ m{^\.+$}) );

    my @split_name  = split /[\s+\/.\-]/, $name;
    my $update_name = movie_fun(@split_name);

    printf "%s -> %s\n", $name, $update_name;
}

sub movie_fun {
    my @split_name = @_;

    return join '', @split_name;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3 ABC ->
3ABC

abc movie (2002)  HDTVRip  576p  Hindi  Eng  BHATTI87 ->
abcmovie(2002)HDTVRip576pHindiEngBHATTI87

Bcd [2011].720p.BRRip.x264.[Dual Audio] [Hindi+English].by K@rtik [ExD Exclusive] ->
Bcd[2011]720pBRRipx264[DualAudio][HindiEnglish]byK@rtik[ExDExclusive]

def (2007) -> 
def(2007)

Gaf-DVDRip-AVI ->
GafDVDRipAVI

Gadks Of Wc (2012) - DVDRip - 1CD - XviD - Subs - [xDM] ->
GadksOfWc(2012)DVDRip1CDXviDSubs[xDM]

Kah - DVDScr - XviD - 1CDRip - [DDR] ->
KahDVDScrXviD1CDRip[DDR]

kaslf.kasl .Ljasj [2007] - x264 - AAC - 1 CD DVDRip - ESubs - MDG ->
kaslfkaslLjasj[2007]x264AAC1CDDVDRipESubsMDG
```